# NTLM authentication in WCF calling .net core API

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I have a WCF service (A) that calls another WCF service (B) with the below configuration.

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

I'm working on calling service B from a .net core (v2.2) service. I have the below setup:

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Ntlm;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

// doesn't have Default as the option. Only TripleDes
//basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDes
basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
basicHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(250000000000);//Timespan in nanoseconds.

EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://");

customerServiceClient = new CustomerServiceClient(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
customerServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = networkCredential;
customerServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

I'm getting the error: Authentication failed because the connection could not be reused. Below is the partial stack of the exception:

```
{"Message":"Authentication failed because the connection could not be reused.","Data":{},"InnerException":{"Message":"Authentication failed because the connection could not be reused.","Data":{},"InnerException":null,"StackTrace":"   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.DrainResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithNtAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean isProxyAuth, HttpConnection connection, HttpConnectionPool connectionPool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n...
```

Please let me know how to get this fixed. Also, this API will be deployed into PCF.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present, `NetCore` doesn’t support message security mode. Thereby the below statement won’t work.

```
basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

But the `NetCore2.2` supports the WCF service with `TransportCredentialOnly` security mode.
Here is an example of invocating the service.

```
 ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("administrator", "abcd1234!");
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = nc;
        var result = client.TestAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

After we add connected service reference, the binding settings and endpoints have already configured in the Reference.cs file.
We just need to modify the default service endpoint address.
[image]
Then we configure the Windows credential on the client-side. On my side, it works. 
Please make sure your client project based on `AspNet Core2.2`
Besides, please refer to the discussion in the official Github repository. It might be useful to you.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2923
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: thanks so much for your time and effort here. But I'm still facing the same issue - "Authentication failed because the connection could not be reused.". Now for the details:

"At present, NetCore doesn’t support message security mode" - does this mean that if a service mandates message security, we can't connect from .net core?

I don't get a service client with an empty constructor at all. So I resort to: customerServiceClient = new TrustedCustomerServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ITrustedCustomerService, "url");

Yes, I've read that discussion as well.

Comment: Yes. Can you create a successful call to the service by using Console application based on Core2.2? What project type is your NetCore(V2.2) service? I am confused that why didn’t you have the constructor. Are you using Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider and ensure the project based on Core2.2.

Comment: I was able to get this working - @Abraham the link you put earlier has a mention of 'AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);'. I put it in the constructor of the proxy and things started working. Thanks so much sir. Will mark your post as the answer.